# Save js variable data in txt

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, terminal, text-files

I have the following code and I need to save `allProducts` in a `.txt` file with json format. How can I achieve that?

```
var fruit = [{"name: x","id: y",..}, {...},...]
var driedFruitsNut = [{"name: x","id: y",..}, {...},...]

fruit.forEach((item) =>{
  item.category =  "Fruits & Vegetables";
  item.subtCategory =  "Fruit";
});

driedFruitsNut.forEach((item) => {
  item.category =  "Fruits & Vegetables";
  item.subtCategory =  "Dried Fruits & Nuts";
});

var allProducts = fruit.concat(driedFruitsNut);
```

I tried something like this; but I have no idea if this is even a correct code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("test.txt", allProducts, function(err) {
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }
});
```

but when I run `node fetchFruitVeg.js` in my terminal. I get a text file looking like this:

[image]

Comment: JSON is not just *JavaScript Object Notation*, but an actual API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("test.txt", JSON.stringify(allProducts), function(err) {
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }
});
```

since allProducts is a javascript object, first you need to convert it into normal string data to write it in a .txt file or .json file